# JQuery : Converting data of a form into a specific format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've got to create a validation plugin with JQuery to extract data of a form and to post them to an Ajax request to a PHP class. My PHP class is taking in parameters data in this format :

- Post data will look like this:

  - {
  - "first_name" : "Test",
  - "visitor_name"  : "Test2",
  - }

For example I'll have a form like this :

```
    <form id="test4">
        <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="users.first_name"><br/>
        <label>Visitor name: </label><input type="text" name="visitor_name" data-validation-rules="first_name"><br/>            
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

In this case, this form should return data like that. But if a form has got data validation rules, I must take it in account and it must appears in the data sent to the Ajax request.

There is the .serializeArray() method in JQuery to do that, but data won't have the good format. And I don't know how to generate data like this with just a form.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use function Which returns True/False Like <form onsubmit="return functValid()">

Comment: If you use validation using ajax, Then it should not submit The data to Backend if  the field is not valid

Comment: You're not going to generate data like this with a form, you'll have to manipulate the data on the client-side before sending or on the server-side when it arrives at your PHP. You may be able to take the $_POST array and hit it with json_encode() on the server side to get what you want - which looks like JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answers
I can not use : onsubmit return functValid, because it's bases on a Resftfull App. So validation will be on Backend post to a Resfull class with the post method.

So I can only use serliaze and manipulate it directly on PHP ?